# MySQL datatype that cannot be empty?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was using the MySQL `INT(11)` data type, but had to change to using `CHAR(45)` because I was dealing with large integers.

Now the `CHAR` is allowing empty strings to be submitted rather than return errors like it should.  Is there another data type I can use?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, and `TEXT` will all allow empty strings, and there's likely not much you can do to change that. You could do validation before your data hits the database, though, which is likely your best bet. Or, perhaps a `BIGINT` column?

Comment: The `(11)` is only for display values -- it does not affect the values `INT` stores.  Why you thought a string based data type was a better idea escapes me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use BIGINT or UNSIGNED BIGINT.

Anyways, you should do some validation at application level, so it will show the user some meaningful error message when the data he sent is not valid. And this is regardless the datatype used.

Answer (score 1):

i would use BigInt, check this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html

Answer (score 1):

if INT doesn't have the range you need, you can 'upgrade' to BIGINT

Generally speaking, if the value is number, you should stick to the numeric data classes-- not doing so usually leads down the road of hard to find bugs and issues.

a half step would be specifing INT as UNSIGNED (basically doubles the range by not including the negative side of the number line in the data space)

See the documentation for more info on [numeric types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html).